# Compile with .NET Native Tool Chain fails in Server 2016 but succeeds in Windows 10

Tags: uwp, .net-native

We have created a UWP project which compiles fine .Net Native Tool chain option in Windows 10 machine.

However, it fails in Windows Server 2016 Standard, which is build server.

Have tried changing the target versions but did not help.

Here're the errors and warnings:-

- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0005: Type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.BackgroundActivatedEventArgs' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'App.OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0003: Method 'App.d__14.MoveNext()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'BackgroundActivatedEventArgs.get_TaskInstance()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : ILT0021: Could not resolve method 'System.Void Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.OnBackgroundActivated($ILT$FakeType0_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_BackgroundActivatedEventArgs)'
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.BackgroundActivatedEventArgs' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'App.OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Method 'App.d__14.MoveNext()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'BackgroundActivatedEventArgs.get_TaskInstance()'. There may have been a missing assembly.

Comment: Does it work in debug mode ?

Comment: Hi, it compiles fine in Debug Mode (without .Native Tool Chain option).

Comment: Could you mind tell us your app's target and min version and installed sdk version in your windows server? Can all sdk be installed successfully in you windows server?

Comment: The SDK installed is Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.18362.1.
The Target Version is "10.0; 14943"
The Min Version is "10.0; Build 10586". 

I tried to uninstall the Windows 10 SDK, in fact, it installed back the same version.

Comment: Changing the combination of Min and Target versions also did not help to resolve the native compilation errors completely (instead of 3 errors, I was getting the 2 errors listed).

The available "Min" versions are: Build 10240, 10586, and 14393.

The available "Target" versions are: Build 10586, and 14393.

Comment: Thanks for the sdk checks. Have found the SDK archives and trying to install 14393 and 10586. Then will build again to see if it resolves. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks a lot, seems you got me the answer - after installing the archived SDKs 14393 and 10586, it is compiled to native Target fine. Many Thanks!

Comment: It's my pleasure, May I converter the comment as an answer for this case.

Comment: Sure, It's ticked now - though I can not vote up due to a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the archived SDKs that match the app's target and min version, it will compile to native target fine. For sdk archive please refer this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)